# Rails 5 and ActiveRecord: reusable filters for listing resources

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

In my application I have a number of pages where I need to display a list of people and allow the user to filter them with a form. And these pages are often similar looking. The filters share parts but still not the same.

I'm wondering how can I avoid repeating almost the same code for different controllers? I tried scopes but I still need to parse parameters and populate form in a view anyway.

Thanks!

Comment: It sounds like you are looking for [partials](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-partials)

Comment: I know about partials of course, but they don't really solve my problem completely. As I mentioned, in the controller I need to parse parameters and build a query.

Comment: Maybe explain what "parse parameters and build a query" means (code examples are always useful). Sounds like a service object would be best to handle this procedure

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: author of https://github.com/dubadub/filtered is here.

ActiveRecord offers a [merge](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/SpawnMethods.html#method-i-merge) method for relations. It intersects two query parts which allows breaking query logic into parts.

Based on that idea I created a gem https://github.com/dubadub/filtered.

In your case it could be something like:

```
# app/controllers/people_controller.rb
class PeopleController < ApplicationController

  before_action :set_filter

  def index
    @people = People.all.merge(@filter)
  end

  private

  def set_filter
    @filter = PersonFilter.new(filter_params)
  end

  def filter_params
    params.fetch(:filter, {}).permit(:age, :active, :sorting)
  end

end
```

```
# app/filters/person_filter.rb
class PersonFilter < ApplicationFilter

  field :age

  field :active do |active|
    -> { joins(:memberships).merge(Membership.where(active: active)) }
  end

  field :sorting do |value|
    order_by, direction = value.values_at("order", "direction")

    case order_by
    when "name"
      -> { order(name: direction) }
    when "age"
      -> { order(age: direction) }
    else
      raise "Incorrect Filter Value"
    end
  end
end
```

```
# app/views/people/index.slim

  = form_for(@filter, url: search_path, method: "GET", as: :filter) do |f|
    .fields
      span Age
       = f.select :age, (18..90).map { |a| [ a, a ] }

    .fields
      span Active
        = f.check_box :active

    .fields
      span Sorting

      span Name
        = f.radio_button :sorting, "name asc"
        = f.radio_button :sorting, "name desc"

      span Age
        = f.radio_button :sorting, "age asc"
        = f.radio_button :sorting, "age desc"      

    .actions
      = f.submit "Filter"
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks, I'll check whether it can solve my problem. If I face any problems with your gem, can I ask for help here?

Answer (score 0):

Have you had a look at query objects?

https://mkdev.me/en/posts/how-to-use-query-objects-to-refactor-rails-sql-queries

They allow you to reuse the code in many places, you'd be able to simply pass the params.permit(...) and get get AR output.

```
# app/queries/user_query.rb
class UserQuery
  attr_accessor :initial_scope
  def initialize(scoped = User.all)
    @initial_scope = initial_scope
  end

  def call(params) # is what you pass from your controller
    scoped = by_email(@initial_scope, params[:email]
    scoped = by_phone(scoped, params[:phone]
    # ...
    scoped
  end

  def by_email(scoped, email = nil)
    email ? where(email: email) : scoped
  end
  def by_phone(scoped, phone = nil)
    phone ? where(phone: phone) : scoped
  end
end

# users_controller.rb
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @users = UserQuery.new(User.all)
      .call(params.permit(:email, :phone))
      .order(id: :desc)
      .limit(100)
  end
end

# some other controller
class RandomController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @users = UserQuery.new(User.where(status: 1))
      .call(params.permit(:email))
      .limit(1)
  end
end
```

You can probably refactor this example to reduce the upfront investment into writing these queries for richer objects, do post here if you come up with alternatives for so that others can learn how to use query objects.